# c# DevExpress GridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress

Good day! How can I implement it if I select some cell, and I want to pass it parameters to the dialog box, but somehow it does not work on DevExpress. Here is the source code, from the usual standard ...

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            new EditDrugs(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()).ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Is there an exception throw? Where?

Comment: I used it the usual standard WinForms, not DevExpress. And now I turn on DevExpress and try to implement the code. Pay attention to the events DataGridView is in it in WinForms, and DevExpress has no such event! ..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int[] selRows = ((GridView)gctNhapHang.MainView).GetSelectedRows();
DataRowView selRow = (DataRowView (((GridView)gctNhapHang.MainView).GetRow(selRows[0]));
string value = selRows["ColumnName"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see you want to get the selected cell/cells value and convert it to use in a dialog

```
foreach (int i in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
                {
                    gridView1.GetSelectedCells(i);
                }
```